# Google URL Shortener | Сокрощение ссылки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я хочу создать свой проект. Но тут проблема, встретился с `Google URL Shortener`.
Я создал свой API. Но я не могу не как понять, как получить сокращенную ссылку по полной. Пробовал через такую ссылку:
[https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=#мой-апи-ключь#&shortUrl=https://goo.gl/x1B3kT](https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=#%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D1%8C#&shortUrl=https://goo.gl/x1B3kT)
Но оно всего лишь дает информацию по уже сокращенной ссылке.

Пробовал так:
[https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=#мой-апи-ключь#&longUrl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask](https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=#%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D1%8C#&longUrl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)
Но выдает ошибку `"message": "Required parameter: shortUrl"`

Буду благодарен, если покажете, как нужно делать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started

При создании ссылки, требуется использовать POST запрос, тело запроса должно представлено быть в json.

Comment: Сделал скрипт вот так https://jsfiddle.net/518ppxb7/  
Не работает

Comment: @yuriy у вас не выбран фреймворк, также не переменные `link`, `api_key` не объявлены.

Comment: А можно подробнее?)
Я не давно в этой сфере работаю
А переменные есть, это честь, я их не скопировал просто

Comment: @yuriy https://jsfiddle.net/518ppxb7/1/ поставьте ваш api_key, и будет работать.

Comment: Ну что за фигня? делал тоже самое и не работало. Спасибо)